# About mac programs and usage data

Tags: software-recommendation, file, file-sharing

Are there any mac professional programs where you can use them for free given you provide the company ( that is responsible for the program ) with detailed usage data ( just pertaining to the program ) for a month or a year ,say?

Comment: Please see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for guidance on how to compose a question here looking for software recommendations. The site works best when questions are not "discussion points" and instead have some specificity to allow good answers to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want system diagnostics, you can always contact Apple or go to an Apple Store for a free diagnostics. If you are talking about networking usage on your Mac, I found a website with a list. I hope this helps!

http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/internet-roundup/4-ways-to-monitor-bandwidth-usage-on-your-mac/

Comment: Are there programs one can 'buy' by offering usage data of the program for a year say? Are there programs you can obtain by bartering or exchanging other info. for it?